# Boost asio asynchronous read and then write

Tags: c++, sockets, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

In my socket communication I have a server where at each connection I want to read data first and after I finished reading, I want to write a response. However I want to do it asynchronously, so I can process many incoming connections. The problem with `async_read` and `async_write` is, that obviously they are asynchronous and when I start to read, the write operation immediately starts too.

So basically my question is:

How to start reading from a socket, then interrupt reading (when I decided by the communication protocol that all data has been sent) and *then* start writing and finally close the socket?

Comment: You should look into the [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) provided with the documentation of Boost.Asio; your questions are covered there. Sorry I cannot point you to the precise files, it's been some time since I used Boost.Asio.

Comment: Voted to close as too broad. Indeed this type of question has many possible answers, and the library examples show all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the second part of your question, look for example at this [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload4.html).

The `async_read` function has the parameters `CompletionCondition completion_condition` and `ReadHandler handler`. These are callbacks. The completion condition should return 0 if you decide that you've read everything you need. Once you are done reading, the `handler` callback is called. You can call `async_write` from the `handler`.